# Ember Simple Auth not setting the Bearer Token

Tags: ember.js

For whatever reason, my authentication seems to be working correctly for logging in, but then I can't got to any routes that use Ember Data. The Bearer Token seems to not be getting set.

Here is my login-form component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    authenticate() {
      let { identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', identification, password)
      .catch((reason) => {
        this.set('errorMessage', reason.error);
        console.log(reason.error);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

This is my authorizer (lives in app/authorizers/application.js)

```
import OAuth2Bearer from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/oauth2-bearer';

export default OAuth2Bearer.extend();
```

and this is my authenticator (lives in app/authenticators/oauth2.js)

```
import OAuth2PasswordGrant from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant';
import config from 'contacts/config/environment';

export default OAuth2PasswordGrant.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint: config.APP.host + '/' + config.APP.namespace + '/authenticate',
});
```

If anyone see's that I'm missing something, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Try this:  session: Ember.inject.service('session')

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd write this up as an answer instead because everything else looks good to me

```
session: Ember.inject.service('session')
```

Although if this were the case it wouldn't make sense that you could call authenticate... hmm, you said the log in seems to work?

Comment: The 'session' argument to .inject.service is not strictly required (though I always use it for clarity).  As long as the key matches the service name, you can call it with .service().  If I wanted to name the key mySession or some such, then I would need to do mySession: Ember.inject.service('session')

Comment: huh no kidding, thanks! Its nice to learn something new. After I saw your answer I realized that made way more sense. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ember-data, you are missing the DataAdapterMixin on your application adapter.

See the example here:

http://log.simplabs.com/post/131698328145/updating-to-ember-simple-auth-10

The relevant code is:

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  authorizer: 'authorizer:application'
});
```

The DataAdapterMixin is what injects the token into the request header, so if authentication is working, but subsequent API requests are not, the problem is likely somewhere in this file.

If you are not using ember-data, then you will have to setup the adapter yourself to manually inject the token into auth requests.  You can see some examples on that link above.

EDIT: Fixed the name of the authorizer, yours lives in authorizers/application.js, so the authorizer is 'authorizer:application'